# Google fonts applying font-weigh:800 when not importing it

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-fonts

I'm importing the size 300 and 400 as per the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400" media="all">
```

Yet I still can apply `font-weight: 800` and it looks different than `font-weight:400` Why? where does it get it from?

Reproduction:
https://jsfiddle.net/7164fk3j/

Even when I only import the font-weight 300:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300" media="all">
```

Reproduction:
https://jsfiddle.net/7164fk3j/1/

How is this working? Is it just making a bold of 300?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fallback Weights

`font-weight` uses fallback weights based on the following algorithm:

> If the exact weight given is unavailable, then the following heuristic
>   is used to determine the weight actually rendered:
>
> - If a weight greater than 500 is given, the closest available heavier    weight is used (or, if there is none, the closest available
>     lighter    weight).
> - If a weight less than 400 is given, the closest available lighter    weight is used (or, if there is none, the closest available heavier
>     weight).
> - If a weight of exactly 400 is given, then 500 is used. If 500 is not    available, then the heuristic for font weights less than 400 is
>     used.
> - If a weight of exactly 500 is given, then 400 is used. If 400 is not    available, then the heuristic for font weights less than 400 is
>     used.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness)

### Synthesis

This explains how the browser maps weights, but where does it get the actual bold version from?

There's a CSS property called `font-synthesis` which provides control over how/when the browser synthesizes aspects of fonts (weight, styles) that are missing.

> The font-synthesis CSS property controls which missing typefaces, bold
>   or italic, may be synthesized by the browser.

This property isn't implemented in many browsers, but its existence suggests that the browser is synthesizing the bold version when it is missing (and that someday this property will give us control over it).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-synthesis)

### Synthesis Source

Putting the two concepts above together, it appears that Chrome will use a weight of 300 as the basis for synthesis, but if you import the 400 version, it will use 400 as the basis and yield a slightly thicker result.

With only 300 weight imported:
[image]

With 300 and 400 weights imported:
[image]

300, 400, and 800 weights imported:
[image]